# How to get PamUSB working again in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-recommendation, login, pam

I use pamusb to authenticate via a USB key. However pamusb seems to have been removed from Ubuntu 15.10.

That's fine, but what is the replacement? How can I do USB key authentication in Ubuntu 15.10?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem so I tried to compile from source, which works straight away after you install libxml-2, dbus-1 and pam development files.

However I get an ugly error when I try to add a device:

# pamusb-conf --add-device=pamusb-key

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pamusb-conf", line 254, in 
    '/org/freedesktop/UDisks')

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in **init**
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)

dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UDisks was not provided by any .service files

I tried to install some python modules (python-dbus, python-pam, python-udiskie, and so on...) but had no luck, but maybe the error will mean something to you, I hope :)

-
Edit

if you install the following launchpad version:

https://launchpad.net/~garhuy/+archive/ubuntu/pamusb

you can avoid compiling from source; however, the error appears to be the missing udisks-1, which you can download from the vivid repository (probably the whole pamsub will work but I didn't try, I am using the compiled version):

The sources.list line to enable the vivid repo:

deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main universe

It works for me, good luck